# Python + convert gpx to csv

Tags: python

I have a list of .gpx files that I would like to convert to csv using python.
I have the following

```
#Set the working directory to the INDIR variable
os.chdir(INDIR)

def parsegpx(f):
    #Parse a GPX file into a list of dictoinaries.  
    #Each dict is one row of the final dataset

    points2 = []
    with open(f, 'r') as gpxfile:
        # print f
        gpx = gpxpy.parse(gpxfile)
        for track in gpx.tracks:
            for segment in track.segments:
                for point in segment.points:
                    dict = {'Timestamp' : point.time,
                            'Latitude' : point.latitude,
                            'Longitude' : point.longitude,
                            'Elevation' : point.elevation
                            }
                    points2.append(dict)
    return points2   

#Parse the gpx files into a pandas dataframe
dirs = os.listdir(INDIR)
df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(parsegpx(f)) for f in dirs], keys=files)
```

However, if I run the code, I get the following error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: invalid start byte

Can anyone help me with that? I tried to add encoding latin-1 to with open but it does not work.

Thanks,
Fede

Comment: Did you have a look at this https://github.com/tkipf/gcn/issues/6

Comment: I tried adding 'rb' instead of 'r' with open but got another error: GPXXMLSyntaxException: Error parsing XML: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1 (<string>, line 1)

Comment: check this simple tool: https://github.com/nidhaloff/gpx_converter

Answer (score 0):

Could we see the gpx file, where the errors occurs? I tried the file https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy/blob/master/test_files/cerknicko-jezero-no-creator.gpx with your codesnippet

```
import gpxpy

def parsegpx():
    points2 = list()
    with open('cerknicko-jezero-no-creator.gpx','r') as gpxfile:
        gpx = gpxpy.parse(gpxfile)
        for track in gpx.tracks:
            for segment in track.segments:
                for point in segment.points:
                    dict = {'Timestamp': point.time,
                            'Latitude': point.latitude,
                            'Longitude': point.longitude,
                            'Elevation': point.elevation
                            }
                    points2.append(dict)
    print(points2)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parsegpx()
```

and get correct results:

```
[{'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 23, 59), 'Elevation': 542.320923, 'Latitude': 45.772175035, 'Longitude': 14.357659249}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 25, 8), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.772089791, 'Longitude': 14.357567383}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 26, 36), 'Elevation': 553.856689, 'Latitude': 45.772063639, 'Longitude': 14.357461184}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 26, 46), 'Elevation': 555.779297, 'Latitude': 45.772002535, 'Longitude': 14.357343167}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 26, 56), 'Elevation': 555.779297, 'Latitude': 45.771906478, 'Longitude': 14.357355237}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 27, 5), 'Elevation': 555.298584, 'Latitude': 45.771813104, 'Longitude': 14.357374264}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 27, 14), 'Elevation': 553.856689, 'Latitude': 45.771737499, 'Longitude': 14.357434446}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 27, 28), 'Elevation': 552.414551, 'Latitude': 45.77164907, 'Longitude': 14.357447689}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 27, 46), 'Elevation': 551.934082, 'Latitude': 45.771551002, 'Longitude': 14.35746965}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 27, 55), 'Elevation': 552.895264, 'Latitude': 45.771471541, 'Longitude': 14.357517259}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 28, 5), 'Elevation': 552.414551, 'Latitude': 45.771403983, 'Longitude': 14.35741676}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 28, 20), 'Elevation': 552.895264, 'Latitude': 45.771397445, 'Longitude': 14.357317435}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 28, 29), 'Elevation': 552.895264, 'Latitude': 45.771366181, 'Longitude': 14.357201932}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 28, 40), 'Elevation': 552.895264, 'Latitude': 45.771278841, 'Longitude': 14.357150551}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 28, 50), 'Elevation': 552.414551, 'Latitude': 45.771187562, 'Longitude': 14.357119622}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 29, 2), 'Elevation': 552.414551, 'Latitude': 45.771096284, 'Longitude': 14.357099757}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 29, 21), 'Elevation': 551.453369, 'Latitude': 45.77100249, 'Longitude': 14.357058266}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 29, 30), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.770905931, 'Longitude': 14.357027002}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 29, 40), 'Elevation': 551.453369, 'Latitude': 45.770820603, 'Longitude': 14.357021051}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 29, 50), 'Elevation': 551.934082, 'Latitude': 45.770730581, 'Longitude': 14.357006885}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 30, 10), 'Elevation': 551.934082, 'Latitude': 45.770663023, 'Longitude': 14.356960701}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 30, 19), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.770596471, 'Longitude': 14.356866069}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 30, 27), 'Elevation': 550.011475, 'Latitude': 45.770515921, 'Longitude': 14.356806893}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 30, 35), 'Elevation': 550.011475, 'Latitude': 45.77044107, 'Longitude': 14.356734473}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 30, 44), 'Elevation': 549.530762, 'Latitude': 45.770396059, 'Longitude': 14.356622826}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 31, 12), 'Elevation': 548.088867, 'Latitude': 45.770342331, 'Longitude': 14.356471952}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 31, 20), 'Elevation': 547.608154, 'Latitude': 45.77032146, 'Longitude': 14.356346475}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 31, 29), 'Elevation': 547.608154, 'Latitude': 45.770324981, 'Longitude': 14.35621555}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 33, 31), 'Elevation': 548.088867, 'Latitude': 45.770286592, 'Longitude': 14.356161403}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 33, 40), 'Elevation': 548.569336, 'Latitude': 45.770196151, 'Longitude': 14.356116978}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 33, 48), 'Elevation': 548.569336, 'Latitude': 45.770110404, 'Longitude': 14.356067609}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 33, 57), 'Elevation': 548.088867, 'Latitude': 45.770022226, 'Longitude': 14.356011786}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 34, 5), 'Elevation': 547.608154, 'Latitude': 45.769934719, 'Longitude': 14.356021928}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 34, 14), 'Elevation': 548.088867, 'Latitude': 45.76983992, 'Longitude': 14.356053527}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 34, 22), 'Elevation': 549.530762, 'Latitude': 45.769755682, 'Longitude': 14.356107507}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 34, 57), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.769677227, 'Longitude': 14.356159139}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 35, 24), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.76961319, 'Longitude': 14.35622938}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 35, 33), 'Elevation': 551.453369, 'Latitude': 45.769536914, 'Longitude': 14.356298028}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 35, 42), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.769446557, 'Longitude': 14.356357036}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 35, 51), 'Elevation': 551.453369, 'Latitude': 45.769356284, 'Longitude': 14.356414033}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 35, 59), 'Elevation': 551.453369, 'Latitude': 45.769272381, 'Longitude': 14.35645544}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 36, 8), 'Elevation': 551.453369, 'Latitude': 45.769192418, 'Longitude': 14.356506485}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 36, 37), 'Elevation': 551.453369, 'Latitude': 45.769169452, 'Longitude': 14.356551832}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 36, 47), 'Elevation': 551.453369, 'Latitude': 45.769182947, 'Longitude': 14.356666999}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 37, 8), 'Elevation': 549.050049, 'Latitude': 45.769151682, 'Longitude': 14.356751824}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 37, 28), 'Elevation': 546.646851, 'Latitude': 45.76906627, 'Longitude': 14.35675744}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 40, 44), 'Elevation': 548.088867, 'Latitude': 45.769023858, 'Longitude': 14.35681561}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 40, 57), 'Elevation': 546.16626, 'Latitude': 45.76893853, 'Longitude': 14.356787531}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 41, 43), 'Elevation': 548.569336, 'Latitude': 45.768877426, 'Longitude': 14.356692648}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 41, 55), 'Elevation': 550.011475, 'Latitude': 45.768804085, 'Longitude': 14.356687954}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 42, 18), 'Elevation': 552.895264, 'Latitude': 45.768726217, 'Longitude': 14.35661763}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 42, 28), 'Elevation': 553.856689, 'Latitude': 45.768643236, 'Longitude': 14.356583264}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 42, 41), 'Elevation': 553.375977, 'Latitude': 45.768552292, 'Longitude': 14.356551664}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 42, 50), 'Elevation': 552.895264, 'Latitude': 45.768532595, 'Longitude': 14.356432641}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 43, 4), 'Elevation': 553.375977, 'Latitude': 45.768547095, 'Longitude': 14.35628864}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 43, 12), 'Elevation': 553.856689, 'Latitude': 45.768509628, 'Longitude': 14.356174478}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 43, 50), 'Elevation': 553.856689, 'Latitude': 45.768411979, 'Longitude': 14.356160816}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 44, 45), 'Elevation': 551.453369, 'Latitude': 45.768287592, 'Longitude': 14.356270535}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 44, 56), 'Elevation': 552.895264, 'Latitude': 45.768202767, 'Longitude': 14.356327029}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 45, 6), 'Elevation': 553.856689, 'Latitude': 45.768117523, 'Longitude': 14.356315462}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 45, 15), 'Elevation': 553.375977, 'Latitude': 45.768031105, 'Longitude': 14.356269529}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 45, 24), 'Elevation': 553.375977, 'Latitude': 45.767948879, 'Longitude': 14.356186548}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 45, 33), 'Elevation': 553.856689, 'Latitude': 45.76787252, 'Longitude': 14.356098538}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 45, 41), 'Elevation': 553.856689, 'Latitude': 45.767792473, 'Longitude': 14.356042296}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 45, 50), 'Elevation': 554.337402, 'Latitude': 45.767695075, 'Longitude': 14.355997872}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 45, 58), 'Elevation': 554.337402, 'Latitude': 45.767609915, 'Longitude': 14.355941545}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 46, 6), 'Elevation': 553.856689, 'Latitude': 45.767528694, 'Longitude': 14.355887398}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 46, 14), 'Elevation': 552.895264, 'Latitude': 45.767441522, 'Longitude': 14.355836436}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 46, 22), 'Elevation': 553.375977, 'Latitude': 45.767348064, 'Longitude': 14.355794108}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 46, 30), 'Elevation': 552.895264, 'Latitude': 45.767251085, 'Longitude': 14.355773237}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 46, 38), 'Elevation': 553.375977, 'Latitude': 45.767154777, 'Longitude': 14.355754713}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 46, 46), 'Elevation': 553.375977, 'Latitude': 45.767059308, 'Longitude': 14.355742307}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 46, 54), 'Elevation': 553.375977, 'Latitude': 45.766966939, 'Longitude': 14.355720598}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 47, 3), 'Elevation': 553.375977, 'Latitude': 45.766870547, 'Longitude': 14.355696207}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 47, 11), 'Elevation': 553.375977, 'Latitude': 45.766783459, 'Longitude': 14.355635773}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 47, 19), 'Elevation': 553.856689, 'Latitude': 45.766693018, 'Longitude': 14.355577519}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 47, 27), 'Elevation': 554.337402, 'Latitude': 45.766603583, 'Longitude': 14.355516415}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 47, 36), 'Elevation': 553.856689, 'Latitude': 45.766510544, 'Longitude': 14.355464783}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 47, 55), 'Elevation': 553.375977, 'Latitude': 45.766405938, 'Longitude': 14.355474003}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 48, 7), 'Elevation': 552.895264, 'Latitude': 45.766316839, 'Longitude': 14.355442068}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 48, 49), 'Elevation': 552.895264, 'Latitude': 45.766348019, 'Longitude': 14.355553379}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 48, 59), 'Elevation': 552.414551, 'Latitude': 45.766360676, 'Longitude': 14.35566226}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 49, 12), 'Elevation': 551.453369, 'Latitude': 45.766296471, 'Longitude': 14.355766783}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 49, 23), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.766229834, 'Longitude': 14.355859822}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 49, 31), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.766162528, 'Longitude': 14.355964931}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 49, 39), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.766103938, 'Longitude': 14.356076159}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 49, 48), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.766047528, 'Longitude': 14.356190655}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 49, 56), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.765984748, 'Longitude': 14.356281515}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 50, 7), 'Elevation': 549.530762, 'Latitude': 45.765921548, 'Longitude': 14.356382936}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 50, 16), 'Elevation': 549.050049, 'Latitude': 45.765888439, 'Longitude': 14.356514532}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 50, 34), 'Elevation': 550.011475, 'Latitude': 45.765891457, 'Longitude': 14.356643446}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 50, 49), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.765914591, 'Longitude': 14.356763558}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 50, 57), 'Elevation': 551.934082, 'Latitude': 45.765939821, 'Longitude': 14.35689331}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 51, 6), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.765952058, 'Longitude': 14.357034126}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 51, 15), 'Elevation': 549.530762, 'Latitude': 45.765955662, 'Longitude': 14.357175026}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 51, 23), 'Elevation': 548.088867, 'Latitude': 45.765975527, 'Longitude': 14.357300419}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 51, 31), 'Elevation': 546.646851, 'Latitude': 45.765997069, 'Longitude': 14.357423885}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 51, 39), 'Elevation': 546.16626, 'Latitude': 45.766027579, 'Longitude': 14.357544836}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 51, 48), 'Elevation': 545.685547, 'Latitude': 45.766058424, 'Longitude': 14.357671989}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 52, 2), 'Elevation': 545.685547, 'Latitude': 45.766093126, 'Longitude': 14.357791012}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 52, 23), 'Elevation': 547.127441, 'Latitude': 45.766090443, 'Longitude': 14.357788749}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 53, 26), 'Elevation': 548.088867, 'Latitude': 45.766053898, 'Longitude': 14.357882291}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 53, 42), 'Elevation': 548.088867, 'Latitude': 45.766070997, 'Longitude': 14.357980527}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 54, 12), 'Elevation': 548.569336, 'Latitude': 45.766096059, 'Longitude': 14.358057389}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 54, 20), 'Elevation': 547.127441, 'Latitude': 45.766129671, 'Longitude': 14.35817088}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 54, 29), 'Elevation': 546.646851, 'Latitude': 45.7661031, 'Longitude': 14.358292501}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 54, 37), 'Elevation': 546.16626, 'Latitude': 45.766075272, 'Longitude': 14.358421164}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 54, 44), 'Elevation': 546.16626, 'Latitude': 45.766054988, 'Longitude': 14.358547311}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 54, 51), 'Elevation': 545.685547, 'Latitude': 45.766025316, 'Longitude': 14.358667256}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 55, 51), 'Elevation': 542.801514, 'Latitude': 45.766022718, 'Longitude': 14.358777311}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 56), 'Elevation': 543.762817, 'Latitude': 45.766049288, 'Longitude': 14.35891578}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 56, 9), 'Elevation': 543.762817, 'Latitude': 45.766078793, 'Longitude': 14.359055925}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 56, 17), 'Elevation': 543.762817, 'Latitude': 45.766111817, 'Longitude': 14.359177044}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 56, 26), 'Elevation': 544.724243, 'Latitude': 45.766153894, 'Longitude': 14.359309645}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 56, 33), 'Elevation': 544.724243, 'Latitude': 45.766190439, 'Longitude': 14.35943244}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 56, 41), 'Elevation': 545.204834, 'Latitude': 45.766230673, 'Longitude': 14.359567473}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 56, 50), 'Elevation': 545.685547, 'Latitude': 45.766320024, 'Longitude': 14.359635953}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 56, 58), 'Elevation': 545.204834, 'Latitude': 45.766417757, 'Longitude': 14.359656069}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 57, 6), 'Elevation': 545.685547, 'Latitude': 45.766501743, 'Longitude': 14.359691609}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 57, 14), 'Elevation': 545.685547, 'Latitude': 45.766521357, 'Longitude': 14.359831335}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 57, 21), 'Elevation': 545.204834, 'Latitude': 45.766533092, 'Longitude': 14.359962847}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 57, 28), 'Elevation': 544.243652, 'Latitude': 45.766544826, 'Longitude': 14.36009503}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 57, 37), 'Elevation': 543.282104, 'Latitude': 45.76654952, 'Longitude': 14.360246742}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 57, 44), 'Elevation': 544.243652, 'Latitude': 45.766525464, 'Longitude': 14.360364089}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 57, 52), 'Elevation': 545.685547, 'Latitude': 45.766478945, 'Longitude': 14.360491158}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 58), 'Elevation': 546.646851, 'Latitude': 45.766446758, 'Longitude': 14.360614205}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 58, 11), 'Elevation': 546.646851, 'Latitude': 45.766479615, 'Longitude': 14.360735575}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 58, 24), 'Elevation': 550.011475, 'Latitude': 45.766559914, 'Longitude': 14.360776898}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 58, 31), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.766651779, 'Longitude': 14.360730127}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 58, 38), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.766742388, 'Longitude': 14.360683607}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 58, 46), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.766840708, 'Longitude': 14.360630047}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 58, 53), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.766935255, 'Longitude': 14.360577241}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 59, 15), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.76722485, 'Longitude': 14.360401221}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 59, 22), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.767318141, 'Longitude': 14.360365933}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 59, 30), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.767415874, 'Longitude': 14.360308684}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 59, 37), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.767510673, 'Longitude': 14.360244479}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 59, 44), 'Elevation': 551.934082, 'Latitude': 45.767606981, 'Longitude': 14.360204581}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 59, 51), 'Elevation': 551.934082, 'Latitude': 45.767699936, 'Longitude': 14.360150099}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 14, 59, 58), 'Elevation': 551.934082, 'Latitude': 45.767789204, 'Longitude': 14.360092515}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 0, 5), 'Elevation': 551.934082, 'Latitude': 45.767891128, 'Longitude': 14.360040715}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 0, 12), 'Elevation': 552.414551, 'Latitude': 45.767986178, 'Longitude': 14.359995034}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 0, 19), 'Elevation': 552.895264, 'Latitude': 45.768079218, 'Longitude': 14.359925045}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 0, 26), 'Elevation': 551.453369, 'Latitude': 45.76816991, 'Longitude': 14.359869137}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 0, 33), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.768261021, 'Longitude': 14.359815493}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 0, 40), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.768350959, 'Longitude': 14.359758329}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 0, 47), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.768450033, 'Longitude': 14.359702338}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 0, 54), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.768536786, 'Longitude': 14.359647771}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 1, 1), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.768630495, 'Longitude': 14.359595804}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 1, 8), 'Elevation': 550.011475, 'Latitude': 45.768726803, 'Longitude': 14.359546769}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 1, 15), 'Elevation': 549.530762, 'Latitude': 45.76882001, 'Longitude': 14.359492119}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 1, 22), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.768925622, 'Longitude': 14.359449288}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 1, 29), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.76902193, 'Longitude': 14.359394386}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 1, 36), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.76912201, 'Longitude': 14.359344598}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 1, 48), 'Elevation': 551.453369, 'Latitude': 45.769292163, 'Longitude': 14.359244769}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 1, 54), 'Elevation': 556.26001, 'Latitude': 45.769382687, 'Longitude': 14.359183414}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 2, 1), 'Elevation': 553.856689, 'Latitude': 45.769459801, 'Longitude': 14.359140582}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 2, 8), 'Elevation': 554.337402, 'Latitude': 45.769552672, 'Longitude': 14.359091381}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 2, 15), 'Elevation': 553.856689, 'Latitude': 45.769652836, 'Longitude': 14.359047711}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 2, 21), 'Elevation': 552.414551, 'Latitude': 45.769740511, 'Longitude': 14.359010328}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 2, 28), 'Elevation': 551.453369, 'Latitude': 45.769836819, 'Longitude': 14.358967999}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 2, 35), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.769914687, 'Longitude': 14.358929778}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 2, 42), 'Elevation': 549.530762, 'Latitude': 45.770003702, 'Longitude': 14.358887114}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 3, 11), 'Elevation': 546.16626, 'Latitude': 45.770254154, 'Longitude': 14.358710088}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 3, 17), 'Elevation': 545.685547, 'Latitude': 45.770357922, 'Longitude': 14.358660635}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 4), 'Elevation': 543.282104, 'Latitude': 45.770934345, 'Longitude': 14.35844304}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 4, 8), 'Elevation': 544.243652, 'Latitude': 45.771037946, 'Longitude': 14.358421247}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 4, 19), 'Elevation': 546.16626, 'Latitude': 45.771127967, 'Longitude': 14.358289903}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 4, 29), 'Elevation': 546.646851, 'Latitude': 45.771174487, 'Longitude': 14.358226871}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 4, 41), 'Elevation': 545.685547, 'Latitude': 45.771373473, 'Longitude': 14.358056802}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 4, 48), 'Elevation': 546.646851, 'Latitude': 45.771503728, 'Longitude': 14.35801967}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 4, 55), 'Elevation': 545.685547, 'Latitude': 45.771614201, 'Longitude': 14.357968373}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 5, 1), 'Elevation': 544.243652, 'Latitude': 45.771710845, 'Longitude': 14.357919926}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 5, 8), 'Elevation': 543.282104, 'Latitude': 45.77182618, 'Longitude': 14.3578579}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 11, 36), 'Elevation': 546.646851, 'Latitude': 45.771829281, 'Longitude': 14.357537627}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 7), 'Elevation': 549.050049, 'Latitude': 45.771894827, 'Longitude': 14.357712474}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 13), 'Elevation': 548.088867, 'Latitude': 45.771840429, 'Longitude': 14.357796963}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 16), 'Elevation': 548.569336, 'Latitude': 45.771743115, 'Longitude': 14.357871311}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 19), 'Elevation': 548.569336, 'Latitude': 45.771622667, 'Longitude': 14.357950101}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 21), 'Elevation': 548.569336, 'Latitude': 45.771533903, 'Longitude': 14.358007936}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 23), 'Elevation': 548.569336, 'Latitude': 45.771430973, 'Longitude': 14.358066106}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 25), 'Elevation': 549.050049, 'Latitude': 45.771324607, 'Longitude': 14.358126372}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 27), 'Elevation': 549.530762, 'Latitude': 45.771206589, 'Longitude': 14.358193427}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 29), 'Elevation': 549.530762, 'Latitude': 45.771082956, 'Longitude': 14.358269367}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 31), 'Elevation': 549.530762, 'Latitude': 45.770953204, 'Longitude': 14.358345978}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 35), 'Elevation': 549.530762, 'Latitude': 45.770695461, 'Longitude': 14.358496601}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 37), 'Elevation': 549.530762, 'Latitude': 45.770566463, 'Longitude': 14.358569104}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 39), 'Elevation': 549.530762, 'Latitude': 45.77043579, 'Longitude': 14.35863968}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 41), 'Elevation': 549.530762, 'Latitude': 45.770300003, 'Longitude': 14.358712351}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 43), 'Elevation': 549.530762, 'Latitude': 45.770154744, 'Longitude': 14.35878695}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 45), 'Elevation': 550.011475, 'Latitude': 45.770012503, 'Longitude': 14.35886398}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 47), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.769874034, 'Longitude': 14.358942099}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 49), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.769732296, 'Longitude': 14.359018458}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 51), 'Elevation': 551.453369, 'Latitude': 45.76959081, 'Longitude': 14.35909356}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 53), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.769447898, 'Longitude': 14.359171093}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 55), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.769310771, 'Longitude': 14.35924829}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 57), 'Elevation': 550.011475, 'Latitude': 45.769169619, 'Longitude': 14.359329343}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 12, 59), 'Elevation': 550.011475, 'Latitude': 45.769021008, 'Longitude': 14.359407965}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 13, 1), 'Elevation': 550.011475, 'Latitude': 45.768874073, 'Longitude': 14.359487928}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 13, 3), 'Elevation': 550.011475, 'Latitude': 45.768733257, 'Longitude': 14.359568143}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 13, 5), 'Elevation': 550.011475, 'Latitude': 45.768587412, 'Longitude': 14.359647604}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 13, 7), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.768448357, 'Longitude': 14.35972916}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 13, 9), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.768309217, 'Longitude': 14.359810464}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 13, 11), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.768167395, 'Longitude': 14.359891182}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 13, 17), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.767732793, 'Longitude': 14.360125121}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 13, 19), 'Elevation': 550.492188, 'Latitude': 45.767598012, 'Longitude': 14.360196032}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 13, 21), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.767468764, 'Longitude': 14.360270463}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 13, 23), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.767328702, 'Longitude': 14.360341541}, {'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 5, 15, 13, 25), 'Elevation': 550.972656, 'Latitude': 45.767197357, 'Longitude': 14.360415721}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. How can I show you the .gpx file? Apologies for the silly questions

Comment: I noted that when I look into dirs, the list ['.DS_Store', 'id_24.gpx']. However only id_24.gpx is the gox file to convert

Comment: Did you solve it? If not, you can paste it into stackoverflow, if the file is not to big. Probably it´s better you share it with github.com or other filesharing possibilities and i will have a look.

Comment: Hi. many thanks for this. you are very kind. I found out that the error was related to the presence of .DS_store in the list. I'll post the solution soon

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [gpxcsv](https://pypi.org/project/gpxcsv/) just for this use case. It can create a bunch of csv files:

```
gpxcsv *.gpx
```

or if you want one big pandas frame in your example:

```
from gpxcsv import gpxtolist
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(gpxtolist(x)) for x in list_of_files])
```

Just requires `lxml`, no need for `gpxpy`. It'll turn any extension tag into a column too, heartrate, temp, etc.